# Fatal error: Namespace declaration statement has to be the very first statement in the script

Tags: php, namespaces

This is an index.php file from a CMS. `Namespace` looks alright to me.

```
<?php 
Namespace
{
    use nutshell\Nutshell;

      /**
     * Nutshell bootsrapper.
     * This overrides Nutshell's default bootsrapper.
     *
     * @global
     * @return Void
     */
    function bootstrap()
    {
        define('PUBLIC_DIR', __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);

          Nutshell::setApplictionPath(__DIR__.'/../private/application');
        Nutshell::registerDefaultConfig('example');                    //your application name

          try
        {
            Nutshell::getInstance()->application->NutsNBolts();
            Nutshell::getInstance()->application->example();        //your application name
        }
        catch(\Exception $exception)
        {
            var_dump($exception);
        }
    }

      /* By including nutshell below, the framework will
     * auto-initiate. Nutshell will detect our custom bootstrap
     * and execute it.
     */
    require __DIR__ . '/../private/lib/nutshell/Nutshell.php';
}
?>
```

Comment: What is the namespace?

Comment: <?php
namespace **helloworld**; http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.definition.php

Comment: It's like this - left blank. But it's worked in previous projects as it is. How do I put a dummy string after?

Comment: I filled the namespace out and I still get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Please add a namespace to your first line,remove  the'Namespace',turn to' 'namespace project1'